# flutter app not taking full width of ipad screen?

Tags: ios, xml, ipad, flutter, flutter-layout

[image: iPad screen hardware]

launching the app on android and iPhones works well while launching it on iPad the app unexpectedly is not taking the full width of the screen!

tried editing the `Main.storyboard` `<view>` width but nothing occurs

```
<view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
</view>
```

[image: Screen on ipad]

Comment: Your screenshot isn't visible.

Comment: fixed now......

Comment: Still it's difficult to understand. Can you take with a picture with your camera if you are using physical iPad?

Comment: Did you use the default counting app? If so, you could report an issue to flutter, I think It's a bug. But there is an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19161) marked as solved, so you should take a look.

Comment: there is not any solution provided in such issue!

Comment: You app isnt configured for iOS as universal, its iphone only, so on iPad it simulates an iphone size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to register your app `Universal`

> Go to Runner > Target > Deployment info

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13):

In the newest XCode version it's not the same anymore as an accepted answer, now you can do it like this.

1. Go to `Runner/BuildSettings` and find `Deployment`
   [image]
2. Click on the `iPhone` next to `Targeted Device Families` and then on `other`
   [image]
3. In the box add `2` and press `enter`
   [image]

And that's it. It will look like this now:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode v15.0+

You need to do change the Targeted devices famillies by **Iphone, iPad**.

1. Open your ios folder with Xcode
2. Click on **Runner** in the left-hand side menu
3. Click on **Runner** in **TARGETS**
4. ***Build Settings => Deployment => Targeted devices famillies***

[image]